# How to determine if request is Fetch or Xhr with chrome.webRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, fetch

In my chrome extension I'm listening for network requests, like this

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(details => {
     console.log(details.type); // for fetch and xhr this is `xmlhttprequest`
},
{ tabId: tab.id, urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"] };
```

I noticed that `details.type` is `xmlhttprequest` for both Fetch and XMLHttpRequest. But I would like to determine if the request was made by Fetch or XMLHttpRequest, is this possible?

Comment: Doesn't `fetch` use `XMLHttpRequest` under the hood?

Comment: really, that would explain my findings